# Domain name is forwarding to my localhost, no idea why

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, localhost

On my local development machine, I have a WAMP setup (Windows Vista Home Premium, Apache 2, MySQL and PHP 5). One of my projects is rehash.dustinfineout.com, which may be related to the problem... For some reason, when I try to visit http://www.rehash.com in a browser, it forwards automatically to 127.0.0.1 loopback/localhost. I discovered this entirely accidentally.

I have already looked at the http.conf and extra/httpd-vhosts.conf Apache configuration files and these are not causing it. I also checked the windows hosts file but that had no entries in it either (C:/WINDOWS/System32/drivers/etc/hosts - maybe there is another location I need to check).

Any ideas?

Just to clarify, rehash.com is NOT my domain.

Comment: Note that rehash.com has relations with sedo parking, [a domain squatter](http://www.whois.net/whois/rehash.com). I would not put it beyond them to use the dns lookups to determine what domains they can "pre-register" for you. i.e. don't use mydomain.com.rehash.com, otherwise you might end up having to buy it from a domain squatter.

Answer (score 5):

```
C:\>nslookup www.rehash.com
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.0.1: Non-existent domain
*** Default servers are not available
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.rehash.com
Address:  127.0.0.1      <----- Whoops
```

Your domain is pointed to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually not my domain at all, I thought it was being caused by the local server though not by the actual domain's nameserver. Makes sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your domain resolves to 127.0.0.1. Youll have to change that =]

Comment: Not my domain. Not my problem :-D Just was confusing because I have a project by the same name, I thought it was occurring all on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

It's their bad (rehash.com). Don't worry about it.

OpenDNS Cache check reports the same
http://www.opendns.com/support/cache/

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly a "bad thing" and they people who've registered this domain might have a good reason for it.

Our web apps often have a requirement for subdomains (abc.mydomain.com and xyz.mydomain.com etc) and to get the subdomains to resolve properly to our development machines we would expect to create entries in our local hosts files. This is very cumbersome, since there is no globbing support in local host files.

This is where domains like rehash.com come in handy. Someone somewhere has donated a domain registration so that *.rehash.com will point back to your local machine without you ever having to do any playing around with your local hosts file.